# Possible bug in Salesforce using Metadata.Operations.retrieve for packaged sObjects?

Tags: apex, lightning, page-layout, metadata.operations

So, currently having an issue using `Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, _layouts_);` in a managed codebase.  The object in question is managed and the *layouts* portion is trying to load **(namespace)sObject-Custom Made Layout** and it is pulling back null.  Whereas if I try **(namespace)sObject-(namespace)Made Layout** the system will retrieve it as expected.

I have tried the callout in the Dev Console multiple times with differing syntax:

**(namespace)sObject-Custom Made Layout**
  **sObject-Custom Made Layout**
  **(namespace)sObject-(namespace)Custom Made Layout**

Even **sObject-(namespace)Custom Made Layout**

None of the solutions work.  Does anyone know of a fix/workaround/issue with this?  Or maybe pointing to a known issue/know why it may not be functioning?

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. `(namespace)sObject-(namespace)Made Layout` is what I would expect to work and you say it does. So why not use it?

Comment: Correct, if it is a layout made by the package owner it is `(namespace)sObject-(namespace)Made Layout` but I need to call one made by a user.  The call does not work in the contexts I gave above.  As I had stated.  the `(namespace)sObject-(namespace)Made Layout` does work as expected.  It's trying to call a user made layout inside of a package created object.

Comment: Oh I see. I would have expected ` (namespace)sObject-Custom Made Layout` to work too. Is "Custom Made Layout" a distinct name compared to "(namespace)Custom Made Layout": for SObject fields accessed from within the package, the namespace version hides the non-namespace version if they are the same ignoring the namespace prefix.

Comment: You would think that would be the accepted case as `(namespace)field__c` would be the packaged vs just `field__c` being user created on a package object is correct.  Sadly it does not though.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue. I don't think the query is unclear.

When trying the below query:
Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, _layouts_);
and _layouts_ is replaced with the below examples, you get mixed results, despite the layouts existing in the org.  
_layouts_ = Account-Account Layout = Success
_layouts_ = pckNamespace__SObject__c-pckNamespace__SObject__c-Layout = Success
_layouts_ = pckNamespace__SObject__c-CUSTOM LAYOUT = No results returned.

Comment: Sorry as an additional comment, in order to validate the name of the layout "pckNamespace__SObject__c-CUSTOM LAYOUT" I used the developerforce workbench, created a package.xml file and successfully retrieved the layout in question.  I believe there to be a bug. Did someone find a solution?